# How are surface area or a revolution and arc length related in Calculus?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I understand that integrals is the area under the function f(x).  and the integral f'(x) if the original f(x).  I understand how to find the arc length on a given interval. I am looking to understand how the surface area of a function rotated around an axis and the arc length are related intuitively.

Comment: First try to consider a line segment parallel to the x-axis that is rotated about the x-axis. Then try to consider a line segment not parallel to the x-axis that is rotated about the x- axis. That way, the surface area "intuitively" follows. Remember that the derivation of the surface area formula comes from an (infinite) sum of frustums whose edges are line segments

Comment: [Quite a nice explanation](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/SurfaceArea.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The first theorem of Pappus directly relates the surface area to the arc length $s$ and the distance traversed by the geometric centroid of the curve (in the plane) during the rotation.
Intuitively, it's as if the arc length was flattened out to form a cylinder of height $s$ and radius equal to the distance between the centroid and the axis of rotation.

So, for example, for a right circular cone of base radius $r$ and height $h$, we have:

- arc length $s=\sqrt{r^2+h^2}$
- curve's centroid is at $\frac{1}{2}r$ from the cone axis

Then

$$S = (\sqrt{r^2+h^2})\left(2\pi \frac{1}{2}r\right)=\pi r \sqrt{r^2+h^2}$$

[Wolfram Alpha](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PappussCentroidTheorem.html) gives a good introduction to this topic.